# По какому API строится работа с реестром действующих пропусков грузового транспорта Москвы?

Tags: api

*Нужно сделать запрос на получения пропусков по номеру авто.*

Данный запрос делается для проверки пропуска на МКАД,ТТК,СК(зоны действия пропусков).
Перерыл кучу ресурсов и не понял, как происходит данная проверка. [Доступная база](https://data.mos.ru/opendata/7704786030-propuska-predostavlyayushchie-pravo-na-vezd-i-peredvijenie-gruzovogo-avtotransporta-v-zonah-ogranicheniya-ego-dvijeniya-na-territorii-goroda-moskvy/data/table?versionNumber=1&releaseNumber=2151)
В данном datasets только номера пропусков, без номера автомобиля.
[Один из множества сервисов](https://proverit-propusk.ru)
Вот сервис предоставляющий нужный функционал. Какой запрос на получение этих данных? Насколько мне известно, есть база где связан пропуск и государственный номер ТС.
[Официальный сервис проверки](http://ovga.mos.ru:8080/)

Comment: https://transport.mos.ru/mostrans/feedback/feedback ?

Comment: Ответ ждать в течении 30 дней. Написал, ответа нет.